# How do I load the CelebA dataset on Google Colab, using torch vision, without running out of memory?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

I am following a tutorial on [DCGAN](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html). Whenever I try to load the CelebA dataset, torchvision uses up all my run-time's memory(12GB) and the runtime crashes. Am looking for ways on how I can load and apply transformations to the dataset without hogging my run-time's resources.

### To Reproduce

Here is the part of the code that is causing issues.

```py
# Root directory for the dataset
data_root = 'data/celeba'
# Spatial size of training images, images are resized to this size.
image_size = 64

celeba_data = datasets.CelebA(data_root,
                              download=True,
                              transform=transforms.Compose([
                                  transforms.Resize(image_size),
                                  transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
                                  transforms.ToTensor(),
                                  transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                                                       std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
                              ]))
```

The full notebook can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1E9SS-QwdXwsjNoAXJ_ea4if2sTksq3LZ?usp=sharing)

### Environment

- PyTorch version: 1.7.1+cu101
- Is debug build: False
- CUDA used to build PyTorch: 10.1
- ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (x86_64)
- GCC version: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
- Clang version: 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
- CMake version: version 3.12.0
- Python version: 3.6 (64-bit runtime)
- Is CUDA available: True
- CUDA runtime version: 10.1.243
- GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: Tesla T4
- Nvidia driver version: 418.67
- cuDNN version: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7.6.5
- HIP runtime version: N/A
- MIOpen runtime version: N/A

Versions of relevant libraries:

- [pip3] numpy==1.19.4
- [pip3] torch==1.7.1+cu101
- [pip3] torchaudio==0.7.2
- pip3] torchsummary==1.5.1
- [pip3] torchtext==0.3.1
- [pip3] torchvision==0.8.2+cu101
- [conda] Could not collect

### Additional Context

Some of the things I have tried are:

- Downloading and loading the dataset on seperate lines. e.g:

```py
# Download the dataset only
datasets.CelebA(data_root, download=True)
# Load the dataset here
celeba_data = datasets.CelebA(data_root, download=False, transforms=...)
```

- Using the `ImageFolder` dataset class instead of the `CelebA` class. e.g:

```py
# Download the dataset only
datasets.CelebA(data_root, download=True)
# Load the dataset using the ImageFolder class
celeba_data = datasets.ImageFolder(data_root, transforms=...)
```

The memory problem is still persistent in either of the cases.

Comment: You need to use [`dataloader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader)

Comment: Looks like the tutorial has been updated to demonstrate the use of the `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder` class. Using @kinyugo's download+unzip recipe (but not their custom dataset), the rest of the tutorial proceeds just fine on colab without throwing memory errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did not manage to find a solution to the memory problem. However, I came up with a workaround, custom dataset. Here is my implementation:

```py
import os
import zipfile 
import gdown
import torch
from natsort import natsorted
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms

## Setup
# Number of gpus available
ngpu = 1
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if (
    torch.cuda.is_available() and ngpu > 0) else 'cpu')

## Fetch data from Google Drive 
# Root directory for the dataset
data_root = 'data/celeba'
# Path to folder with the dataset
dataset_folder = f'{data_root}/img_align_celeba'
# URL for the CelebA dataset
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1cNIac61PSA_LqDFYFUeyaQYekYPc75NH'
# Path to download the dataset to
download_path = f'{data_root}/img_align_celeba.zip'

# Create required directories 
if not os.path.exists(data_root):
  os.makedirs(data_root)
  os.makedirs(dataset_folder)

# Download the dataset from google drive
gdown.download(url, download_path, quiet=False)

# Unzip the downloaded file 
with zipfile.ZipFile(download_path, 'r') as ziphandler:
  ziphandler.extractall(dataset_folder)

## Create a custom Dataset class
class CelebADataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
    """
    Args:
      root_dir (string): Directory with all the images
      transform (callable, optional): transform to be applied to each image sample
    """
    # Read names of images in the root directory
    image_names = os.listdir(root_dir)

    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transform = transform 
    self.image_names = natsorted(image_names)

  def __len__(self): 
    return len(self.image_names)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    # Get the path to the image 
    img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.image_names[idx])
    # Load image and convert it to RGB
    img = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
    # Apply transformations to the image
    if self.transform:
      img = self.transform(img)

    return img

## Load the dataset 
# Path to directory with all the images
img_folder = f'{dataset_folder}/img_align_celeba'
# Spatial size of training images, images are resized to this size.
image_size = 64
# Transformations to be applied to each individual image sample
transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(image_size),
    transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                          std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
])
# Load the dataset from file and apply transformations
celeba_dataset = CelebADataset(img_folder, transform)

## Create a dataloader 
# Batch size during training
batch_size = 128
# Number of workers for the dataloader
num_workers = 0 if device.type == 'cuda' else 2
# Whether to put fetched data tensors to pinned memory
pin_memory = True if device.type == 'cuda' else False

celeba_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(celeba_dataset,
                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                num_workers=num_workers,
                                                pin_memory=pin_memory,
                                                shuffle=True)
```

This implementation is memory efficient and works for my use case, even during training the memory used averages around(4GB). I would however, appreciate further intuition as to what might be causing the memory problems.

Comment: url link to download celeba doesn't work, here is the new url `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7EVK8r0v71pTUZsaXdaSnZBZzg?resourcekey=0-rJlzl934LzC-Xp28GeIBzQ`

Comment: For direct download, the link is actually `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms

# Root directory for the dataset
data_root = 'data/celeba'
# Spatial size of training images, images are resized to this size.
image_size = 64
# batch size
batch_size = 10

transform=transforms.Compose([
                              transforms.Resize(image_size),
                              transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
                              transforms.ToTensor(),
                              transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                                                   std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

dataset = ImageFolder(data_root, transform)

data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=8, drop_last=True)
```

More details for `Dataloader` class may be looked up [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html).
The above answer, courtesy [this kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/ashishpatel26/gan-beginner-tutorial-for-pytorch-celeba-dataset).

Comment: To iterate over this `data_loader`, use the following for loop: `for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(data_loader):`; where images is a batch-ful of images.

Comment: The memory issue is still persistent even after this.